# Transform sentences ending with multiple question marks (?) or exclamation marks (!) into a sentence only ending with one

Tags: php, regex

Create a function that transforms sentences ending with multiple question marks (?)
or exclamation marks (!) into a sentence only ending with one.

("What went wrong?????????") ➞ "What went wrong?"
("Oh my goodness!!!") ➞ "Oh my goodness!"
("I just!!! can!!! not!!! believe!!! it!!!") ➞ "I just!!! can!!! not!!! believe!!!
it!"
// Only change repeating punctuation at the end of the sentence.
("Oh my goodness!") ➞ "Oh my goodness!"
// Do not change sentences where there exists only one or zero exclamation
marks/question marks.
("I just cannot believe it.") ➞ "I just cannot believe it."

How to solve this anyone have idea

```
<?php
$text="hgj dfsg jsdgfjg??? jgsdjfgj ??? jkjsdfgjfk ??";
$a=preg_replace( '{\\?+}', '?', $text );
echo $a;
?>
```

I'm using this code but its replacing from all place but it should replace from last occurrence according the need.
can any one give the solution for this?

- Note - regular expression is not compulsory  to use, you can use any method to get answer

Comment: Can they be mixed? Like `?!` `!?!?`

Comment: no if its mixed then dont replace, only if more the 1 occurrence of ? and !  at the end of the string need to replace with single

Comment: Is this about single lines? Or can it also be mutiple strings over multiple lines? The parenthesis and double quotes in the question are there for clarity?

Comment: yes parenthesis and double quotes are for clarity . and the string will be single line

Comment: Like this? `([?!])\1++(?!\S)(?!.*(?:!!|\?\?))` https://regex101.com/r/cgqPYT/1

Answer (score 0):

When use single lines, you might use a backreference to capture the same character and match at least 2 chars, as you don't have to replace a single char with itself when only matching 1 char.

```
([?!])\1++(?!\S)(?!.*(?:!!|\?\?)(?!\S))
```

In the replacement use group 1 like `$1`

**Explanation**

- `([?!])` Capture either ? Or ! in **group 1**
- `\1++` Backreference to group 1, repeat 1+ times with a possessive quantifier `++` to prevent some backtracking
- `(?!\S)` Negative lookahead, assert a whitespace boundary to the right
- `(?!.*(?:!!|\?\?)(?!\S))` Negative lookahead, assert no more occurrence of ?? Or !! to the right with a whitespace boundary to the right

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6nfQEq/1)

---

If you don't want to cross a dot, exclamation or question mark followed by a space in between:

```
([?!])\1++(?!\S)(?!(?:(?![.?!]\h).)*(?:(?:!!|\?\?)(?!\S)|[.?!]$))
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZXgeEd/1)